# how can I update scipy in winpython on windows?

Tags: python, windows, scipy

I have winpython installed and I would like to update scipy to the version 0.14. 
How can I do that?  Should I reinstall winpython completely?

EDIT:

If I run `pip install --upgrade scipy` from the `WinPython Command Prompt` I receive this error:

```
----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Users\donbeo\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5.amd64\python.exe -c
 "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\donbeo\\appdata\\local\\temp\
\pip_build_donbeo\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:
\users\donbeo\appdata\local\temp\pip-puzp_i-record\install-record.txt --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\donbeo\
appdata\local\temp\pip_build_donbeo\scipy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\donbeo\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\setting
s\pip\pip.log
```

C:\Users\donbeo\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5.amd64>pip install --upgrade
 scipy

Comment: can you not just use pip?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have updated the question. The same command works on ubuntu. I do not know if I am doing something wrong here on windows.

Comment: it can be a pain on windows installing anything, I added an answer with a link to prebuilt binaries.

Answer (score 5):

Christoph Gohlke [now provides wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), so starting Winpython of January 2015, you may also be able to do that:

- Download the correct `.whl` file for your Python version (e.g. `cp33` for Python 3.3 and `win32` for 32-Bit) to some location, e.g. `D:\scipy\`
- Launch the WinPython Command Prompt
- Type

  ```
  pip install --no-index --upgrade D:\scipy\scipy‑0.15.0‑cp33‑none‑win32.whl
  ```

It should give you an output like this, for example for Python 3.3 32-Bit:

```
D:\result_tests\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.5_build5\python-3.3.5>pip install --no-index --upgrade D:\here_is_scip\scipy-0.15.0-cp33-none-win32.whl
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Processing d:\here_is_scip\scipy-0.15.0-cp33-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.14.1
    Uninstalling scipy-0.14.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-0.14.1

Successfully installed scipy-0.15.0

D:\result_tests\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.5_build5\python-3.3.5>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is caused because you are not running the prompt with administrator privileges. Locate the DOS-like "command prompt" program, then right-click on it and choose "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for windows is to use  [Christoph Gohlke's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack) prebuilt binaries which is also a recommended way to install according to [wppm](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/wiki/WPPM) :

Comment: I have tried but I have python installed in a local folder (I have just extracted winpython in a folder) and so scipy from the website can not be installed because python is not in the variable path.  Is there an easier way to solve?

Comment: can you add a path to winpython to include your system python packages or use the package manager to install?

Comment: I would prefer to  avoid that. I should call the people of the IT department in this case.